# Django template doesn't work with booleans?

Tags: python, html, django, templates, boolean

I have the following template that only should activate when `test` is `true`.

```
{% if test %}
  <h1>The value of test was {{ test }} </h1>
{% endif %}
```

In views.py, `test` is being set to `false`.  However, in the resulting html, I see the phrase that `The value of test was false`.  How can I instead only get this template to activate when `test` is `true`?

Comment: What template lib is this?

Comment: Sorry for not adding at first, this is the django template library.  T.J, thank you for the heads up.

Comment: Can you show the view? Templates do work correctly with booleans, but if `test` is e.g. the string `'false'`, that'd be exactly what you get.

Comment: Are you sure you are passing `False` and not `"false"`. If you passed a bool the message should read false with an uppercase `F`

Comment: @ Wombatz, that was the problem.  If you'd like to post that as an answer, then I'd be able to accept that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the Boolean `False` instead of the string `"false"`.  You can tell which one you're passing by seeing whether `{{ test }}` is being displayed as `False`, in which case it's a boolean, or `false`, in which case you're passing a string.